# SwiftUI tap gesture blocks item deleting action in List

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

So I have a view with `List`, also this view has side menu. I added `tapGesture` to my `VStack` to dismiss side menu when it's open, but then I face issue, `tapGesture` is blocking `onDelete` method of `List`. Any ideas how to fix that??

Here is code example:

```
VStack {
.....
    List {
          ForEach(){
           //list elements here
          }
          .onDelete {
            // delete action here
          }
    }
}
.onTapGesture {
// action here 
}
```

Also, if while deleting I swipe once till the end, it's working. But if I swipe just a little and try to press `Delete` button nothing happens.

Comment: Hey Alex, did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Replace your `.onTapGesture` with the `simultaneousGesture` modifier.

```
.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
    // action here 
})
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesnt work, it's still the same.

Comment: Came across this in macOS noticing that list selection was blocked by tap/doubletap simultaneous gesture placed within a List item, although TextFields still work as expected.